# Google map cannot display when I install APK that I produced

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, apk

I have produced the apk. After I install it, the google map cannot display.

Before I produced that apk, I have tried to run as Android application in Eclipse and the map can display.

That is the steps I produce the apk :

1. Click the project  AndroidManifest.xml
2. Click Use the Export Wizard to export and sign an APK
3. Select my project
4. Create new keystore (Location:Desktop / password......)
5. Create new key (Alias:project name / password..... / validity: 100 years / First and last name:Liar)
6. Destination APK file : Desktop

Is this step wrong? Or another thing that I did not notice?

How can I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: maybe you are using a debug key to show the maps in your Manifest, that could be a reason of why you can not use them, remember that production keys are only valid for published apps, if you have not changed it, you will have to :)

Comment: You have to use different keys for debug & while making an apk.

Comment: Will I register the new key for Google API Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
keytool -list -v -keystore your_keystore_name -alias your_alias_name
```

Replace your_keystore_name with the fully-qualified path and name of the keystore, including the .keystore extension. Replace your_alias_name with the alias that you assigned to the certificate when you created it.

Create api key correspoding to your release keystore and use it.

Answer (score 0):

While creating the

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBoJVDT4W********" /> , for getting the value, the SHA1 and key-store location need to specify properly
```